# Repeat each line in a text n times

Tags: command-line, bash, awk

I have a file that looks like this

```
888
924
873
1374
.....
```

The dots indicate that I have many more string, around 3000.
I want repeat each string n time, to have something like this;

```
888
888
888
924
924
924
873
873
873
....
```

I tried to write a small bash code:

```
#! bin/bash

while IFS= read -r line

do 
    awk 'NR==line'
    awk 'NR==line'
    awk 'NR==line'
done < /<PATH_TO_FILE>
```

But I get no results. I thought that this was a quite easy task, but obviously I am missing something. Any advise?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can easily be done in `perl`:

```
perl -ne 'print $_ x 3' file
```

the above oneliner output:

```
$ perl -ne 'print $_ x 3' file
888
888
888
924
924
924
873
873
873
1374
1374
1374
```

Just change the sample value for your needs.

An `awk` solution:

```
awk '{for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) print $1}' file
```

To fix your bash script I would use the following snippet instead:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do
    for i in {1..3}; do echo $line; done
done < ./file
```

Comment: `perl -ne 'print $_ x 3' file` is even easier.

Comment: @choroba: indeed, I tried but forgot that it required spaces around the `x` operator. Thanks. I'm updating the answer.

Comment: great thanks. I would prefer an awk solution, because I know it a bit better and I have to edit the file even more after performing this first step.

Comment: @efrem: I've updated my answer with an `awk` solution

Comment: works perfectly, any idea why my code sucked?

Comment: @efrem: It seems that the awk commands were unneeded. See my update

Answer (score 2):

There is a nice trick to print a string repeatedly:

```
$ printf "%0.s-" {1..10}
----------
```

Based on that, we can loop through the file and print the line as many times as we indicate in the brace expression:

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
printf "%0.s$line\n" {1..3}
done < file
```

#### Test

```
                          change this number as you wish
                                                       v
$ while IFS= read -r line; do printf "%0.s$line\n" {1..3}; done < a
888
888
888
924
924
924
873
873
873
1374
1374
1374
```

Although my preference would be to use an `awk` like this, very similar to what others posted before (nice answers by the way):

```
awk -v tot=3 '{for (i=1; i<=tot; i++) print}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply do this through sed.

```
$ sed 's/\(.*\)/\1\n\1\n\1/g' file
888
888
888
924
924
924
873
873
873
1374
1374
1374
```